# GCP - windows-startup-script metadata

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform

I am preparing Windows VM instance in GCP. I am using a startup script to perform VM initial configuration. I would like to pass multiple values using `windows-startup-script metadata`. I have all components prepared, I need to pass metadata name `tags`, metadata value will be a list of values, like: `Parameter tag A, Parameter tag B, Parameter tag C`. When I am using comma "," as a separator, in `command line` output I can see incorrect format, like below.

[image]

Question is how these values should be supplied in the metadata section.

[image]

Comment: What is incorrect? Can you describe what are you expecting?

Comment: Hi, expected output format is: --metadata="windows-startup-script-url=https://storage.cloud.google.com/$bucketname/test.ps1,tags=Parameter tag A, Parameter tag B, Parameter tag C,Priority=Critical,langs=en". And this is just extract from the entire command, its just metadata section.

Answer (score 0):

The command line is correctly generated. In fact, in the metadata list, the coma `,` is the separator. The command generated escape the coma as separator and generate a correct format to be accepted.

You can also change the separator, for example use the semicolon `;`, and update your script accordingly.

---

**EDIT 1**

The proposed command line is compliant with Linux, not with Windows terminal (powershell or Dos). I tested on my side and you can simply put between double quote your value with space and `;`

```
gcloud beta compute instances create instance-2 --zone=us-central1-a --machine-type=f1-micro --metadata=test="para1=a; para2=b; para3=c"
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tested the sh script, metadata section. I used structure like this: url=storage.cloud.google.com/$bucketname/test.ps1,products=Parameter tag A;Parameter tag B;Parameter tag C,Priority=Critical,langs=en". I used ";" as a separator in the "products" list, and it doesn't work as expected. Even one product from the list is not selected as expected. Do You have some idea what is wrong?

Comment: You have to escape the spaces with a backslash `\`. or try to add the value part of the metadata between double quote `"` to escape the spaces `products="Param 1; Param 2;"`

Comment: I was trying many combinations and for me unfortunately it doesn't work, still have incorrect format in the command line output :(

Comment: Are you on Windows (dos or powershell), linux or mac environment with you run the command?

Comment: Its Windows environment

Comment: Hi, Good morning, any new ideas, how to resolve that problem?

Comment: Can you detail what is the intended use to provide as metadata the `tags=Parameter tag A...`? 
As far I understand, you are creating your instance using the shell and providing a startup script url where the powershell script is stored. As a workaround I suggest to declare the tag variables in the same script.
For more information, you can see the documentation for [providing a startup script for Window instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script_for_windows_instances) -

Comment: - and [Providing a startup script stored on Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#cloud-storage).

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it work on your side now?